# Server Error in '/' Application c# MVC5 logging in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to log in, and this is the error I'm getting.

Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'RoleId'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'UserId'.
Invalid column name 'RoleId'.

```
Line 415:        {
Line 416:            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
Line 417:            var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
Line 418:            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
Line 419:        }
```

I've tried messing around on a backup with the given tables and have gotten absolutely nowhere. I have no idea where this error message is coming from.

Comment: Are you using all the latest versions of any NuGet packages you have installed? If you've recently upgraded to a later version of `AspNet.Identity`, for example, they changed the underlying database schema it uses to add more fields, so it's possible you need to migrate the membership database.

Comment: Yeah everything is the latest version. Although I have just switched databases and therefore had to generate the database through an EDMX script. Everything is working fine except this weird bit